# Nunit3 How rewrite code from Nunit2

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

In nunit2 I used this code:

```
 yield return new TestCaseData(sourceWordsModelEmpty, combinationsModelEmpty).SetName("FindCombinationsTest - Empty").Throws(typeof(Exception));
```

How can I use it in Nuni3?

Comment: You need to supply some context for this single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having trouble with the `Throws`. Remove it and pass in the exception type as an additional parameter. Then in your test, wrap the code that throws the exception in an `Assert.Throws`.